# android LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL not detecting usb camera

Tags: android, android-camera

the android LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL not detecting usb camera it always giving 2 cameras connected but i connected my USB Camera through OTG cable but not getting
the total cameras as 3 why?

Help me

Comment: Does the device's built-in camera app recognize your USB camera?

Comment: @commonsware no not detecting

Comment: I have not tried a USB camera via OTG. I do not know if that is normally supported or not. Certainly, `LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL` suggests that Android 5.0+ is looking to support external cameras. But I don't know what the expected behavior is for your scenario.

Comment: @commonsware just i want to print totalcameras as 3 (2 cameras of the device and 1 external usb camera).if it is possible then i will move forward

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?